# How can I disable this 'feature' of Emac's regexp replace (unwanted capitalization)

Tags: regex, emacs

Say I have a buffer which contains:

```
Hello
HELLO
```

and I run a regexp-replace going from `\(.*\)` to `\1 World!`

The result is

```
Hello World!
HELLO WORLD!
```

While what I want is

```
Hello World!
HELLO World!
```

Is there an option somewhere I can set to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set `case-replace` to `nil`, like this:

```
(setq case-replace nil)
```

Then it will preserve the case in the replace.

Answer (score 1):

C-h f query-replace-regexp RET